# How to write a SQL query with dynamic fields?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, sql

For example, I have a DE table(DE_A) with field a, b, c, d. The client may add e,f,g in the future due to their needs.

My current SQL Query activity is :

```
SELECT CONCAT("prefix", a) AS a, CONCAT(b, "suffix") AS b, c,d FROM DE_A
```

The query result will be stored into another DE table(DE_B).

I have a DE table which store field c, d. The client can add e,f,g in this DE table.

How can I modify my current SQL query so that the SQL can get field e,f,g automatically in the future?

Comment: **The query result will be stored into another DE table.**,  does that mean you are going to store the query result into altogether another DE table for any reason?

Comment: Yes, that's my purpose

Comment: @Gortonington has good solution indeed. Just wanted to confirm, is the logic is too complicated to resolve by Fieldset and a dynamic query?

Comment: Actually is permission problem. The original table could be seen by current BU, while result DE table can share across all BU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done inside of SFMC SQL queries, but can still be done.

What I would do is create a script activity utilizing SSJS to dynamically create, update and run the query.

1. First I would use the SSJS to create the query with conditionals that look up what the fields are inside the DE and then add in those fields to your query.
2. I would then have the [SSJS update the query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_queryDefinitionUpdate.htm) that you have stored in the UI via API.
3. Finally I would then use the [script to run the newly updated query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_queryDefinitionPerform.htm).

Example1: (conditional to add query text)
`if (e) { queryTextVar += '{{your var sql stuff here}}' };`

Example 2: (Update Query)

```
var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("myQueryDef");

var status = qd.Update({
    Name : yourQueryNameVar,
    QueryText : queryTextVar
});
```

Example 3: (Running the query)

```
var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("myQueryDef");
var status = qd.Perform();
```

You can then add this script into an Automation and have it run at your set schedule or triggered off of a file drop.

Comment: I will give a try first. Efficiency is my main concern as I know SSJS is slower than SQL query. It may timeout when running.

Comment: The query would run independently of the SSJS.  Basically the SSJS would create the query. Upload the query then flag it to run. At this point the SSJS part is done.  Then the query would start and run as normal.  This should only add a couple minutes overall to your total time, but should not affect the run time of the query itself at all.

Comment: When I run `qd.Perform()` it shows `Exception occurred during [Schedule::Start] ErrorID = 614491250`. I'm sure my SQL is correct as I run it on SQL activities it shows success message. My codes combines Example 2 and 3 together.

Comment: OK, I got an workaround. I created an SQL query via SSJS. Then put the SQL query inside automations. It works like a charm!

Comment: Perfect! Glad it was working. What might have been the issue is that if you ran Perform too soon after the update, the query may have still been updating/saving and not been able to initiate.

Comment: I see. I think the docs should clearly state this point, or run `perform` immediately will cause exception.